# I would like this CSS to apply to those within a HTML element with class 'details'

Tags: html, css

This should be relatively easy but I cannot seem to wrap up the following list of css in such a way that it will ONLY take effect for html elements within a div which has a class of 'details'. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
table {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 0 20px;
margin-top:20px;
border-collapse: separate;
border-collapse: collapse; */
border-spacing: 0;
}

tr {
display: table-row;
vertical-align: inherit;
border-color: inherit;
}

th {
color: #888;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 18px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
padding: 0 0 5px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 12px;
width: 33.333%;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 18px;
padding: 7px 10px;
text-align: left;
vertical-align: top;
}

tr {
display: table-row;
vertical-align: inherit;
border-color: inherit;
}

td ,.detailText{
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: 600;
padding: 0 5px 0 0;
line-height: 18px;
}
```

Comment: HTML sample pelase. Your Title, Question and code make no sense currently and will just attract load of probably bad answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML, use `<div class="details">`

Here is your CSS

```
.details table {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-collapse: collapse; */
    border-spacing: 0;
    }

.details tr {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    border-color: inherit;
    }

.details th {
    color: #888;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0 0 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 33.333%;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    }

.details tr {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    border-color: inherit;
    }

.details td ,.detailText{
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
    line-height: 18px;
    }
```

Comment: Is there no way to make a block of #details rather than applying the rule on every selector?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of I'm afraid.

Comment: @RenegadeAndy It's possible to "make a block of #details" with CSS pre-processors like Sass and Less (my preference). But it just saves some typing, as it ends getting processed down to vanilla CSS that looks exactly like the above anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just prepend `.details` to all your selectors, e.g.

```
.details table {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-collapse: collapse; */
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.details tr {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    border-color: inherit;
}
/* So on and so forth */
```

... and etc. If you want to apply it across a block of CSS (as mentioned in your comment), you will have to look at CSS preprocessors, such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). An example of a SASS written in SCSS syntax ([more in depth description](http://thesassway.com/editorial/sass-vs-scss-which-syntax-is-better)) would be:

```
.details {
    table {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 0 20px;
        margin-top:20px;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-collapse: collapse; */
        border-spacing: 0;
    }

    tr {
        display: table-row;
        vertical-align: inherit;
        border-color: inherit;
    }

    th {
        color: #888;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 18px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        padding: 0 0 5px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 12px;
        width: 33.333%;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 18px;
        padding: 7px 10px;
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    tr {
        display: table-row;
        vertical-align: inherit;
        border-color: inherit;
    }

    td ,.detailText{
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding: 0 5px 0 0;
        line-height: 18px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there no way to apply the .details across a block of css rather than doing it manually for every element of css?

Comment: If you want to do that, you might have to look at using CSS preprocessors, which allows for CSS nesting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll go off your title to use `id` (your description says `class`).

Just prepend the `id` to your CSS elements.

```
#details table { ... }

#details tr {... }
```

Etc.

It works the same with a class, just different markup.

```
.details table { ... }

.details tr {... }
```

Full sample:

```css
#details p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Paragraph.</p>
<div id="details">
  <p>Details paragraph.</p>
</div>
```